# Enable / Disable button in Angular Form based on API Response

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-submit

I am using Angular8 with Reactive form. Initially I'm disabling the Submit button until the entire form is filled with valid data.

```
<div>
  <form>
     ...........
  </for>
  <button [disabled]="(checkifSaveEnabled() && !formCreateNewPlan.valid)" 
       (click)="createNewPlan()">Save</button>
</div>
```

In the class (TS) file:

```
checkifSaveEnabled() {
  if (this.formCreateNewPlan.pristine || !this.formCreateNewPlan.valid) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

createNewPlan(): void {
   this.submitted = true;
   this.myservice.create(this.formCreateNewPlan.value).subscribe(result => {
   if (result.success && result.data.planId > 0) {
      ... 
   }
}
```

Everything is working fine here. But, I want to disable the Button On Submit (to avoid multiple clicks) and Make it enable back if I get any errors from my Service (API) response. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `submitted` that will be true if API is in progress and will become false if API resolves or reject.
Now you can use finalize operator to set `submitted` to false inside it. It will execute after the success or error block of observable.

```
createNewPlan(): void {
   this.submitted = true;
   this.myservice.create(this.formCreateNewPlan.value)
.pipe(finalize(() => { this.submitted = false; }))
.subscribe(result => {
   if (result.success && result.data.planId > 0) {
   }

}, (error) => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

Corresponding change in Template

```
<button [disabled]="submitted || (checkifSaveEnabled() && !formCreateNewPlan.valid)" 
       (click)="createNewPlan()">Save</button>
```

Comment: on submit, button is disabling now. If I get a Server error say "Duplicate record" and I want to fix this, how to re enable it after correcting the values in a Form?

Comment: I did not understand your point. After the success or error response, the button will be enabled automatically because of the code written inside the finalize block. Please let me know if I miss something here.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add one `this.submitted` in the disabled attribute of button, see below code

```
<button [disabled]="submitted || (checkifSaveEnabled() && !formCreateNewPlan.valid)" 
       (click)="createNewPlan()">Save</button>
```

Comment: on submit, button is disabling now. If I get a Server error say and I want to fix this, how to re enable it after correcting the values in a Form?

Comment: after server response you can make `this.submitted=false` (both in success or error case), this will enable the button

Comment: but it'll enable immediately after getting error. It should enable after  making corrections in Form

Comment: then in this case change `||` to `&&`

Comment: in && case, initially button will get enabled.

Comment: ok... got your problem ... you can keep `||` as it is and call form validation method after server response and as per response make `this.submitted=false` ... hope this should help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223282/discussion-between-shreekumar-s-and-bhushan-kawadkar).